# SQLAlchemy-friendly UPDATE instead of INSERT trigger

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have an AuthToken table with an associated AuthTokenHist table where I would like to record all the state changes in AuthToken. I would like to make it transparent to the model's user that there is any archiving going on however. So, ideally, they would just create new AuthTokens using the same PK of an existing AuthToken and the database would update the row in AuthToken and create a new row in AuthTokenHist when AuthToken already has an entry for that PK.

I realize what I'm asking for is very close to an upsert, but I'm on an old postgresql version with no support for upserts. Also, from SQLAlchemy's point of view, I would like the user to just think they're constructing a new AuthToken even when they're actually UPDATE-ing an existing one.

I've tried doing this with an INSERT trigger which basically DELETEs the existing AuthToken, INSERTs a row into AuthTokenHist and also returns NEW. I can't get past the sqlalchemy session though which prohibits having two objects with the same PK in the same session

`FlushError: New instance <AuthToken at 0x3f51150> with identity key (<class 'models.AuthToken'>, (15L, u'c41ffcc3-5dbc-4042-a990-0c
18020cf77b')) conflicts with persistent instance <AuthToken at 0x3f61350>`